# Auth0 gradle dependency error

Tags: android, authentication, gradle

I am trying to work with Auth0 in my project and when I try to include it in the `build.gradle` file I get an error. I've tried adding the following:

`compile 'com.auth0.android:auth0:1.10.0'`

and

`compile 'com.auth0.android:auth0:1.+'`

I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

I ran `gradlew build --stacktrace` and got this:

```
14:31:51.285 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
14:31:51.285 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
14:31:51.285 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
14:31:51.285 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:31:51.285 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
14:31:51.285 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
14:31:51.285 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
14:31:51.286 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
14:31:51.286 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
14:31:51.286 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 3.378 secs
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Update

Opened `AndroidManifest.xml` and found this message in the `Merged Manifest`

```
Merging Errors: Error: Attribute data@host at AndroidManifest.xml requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <auth0Domain> is provided. app main manifest (this file) Error: Attribute data@scheme at AndroidManifest.xml requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <auth0Scheme> is provided. app main manifest (this file)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Answering my own question here:
The merged manifest had the error

```
Attribute data@host at AndroidManifest.xml requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <auth0Domain> is provided. app main manifest (this file) Error: Attribute data@scheme at AndroidManifest.xml requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <auth0Scheme> is provided. app main manifest (this file)
```

Basically saying that `auth0Domain` and `auth0Scheme` needed values declared.

I needed to enter the line

```
manifestPlaceholders = [auth0Domain: "@string/com_auth0_domain", auth0Scheme: "demo"]
```

in the `build.gradle` file and then it compile just fine.

Basically follow through instructions before deciding that you're stuck, [those instructions were here](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/android/00-login).

Comment: It is worth noting that the `manifestPlaceholders` line needs to be in the defaultConfig{...} block.

Comment: How can I set domain and scheme dynamic?